# How to deactivate the purple highlighting for html color names in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using the plugin "Color Highlighter" that allows me to directly view the color used but the default purple highlighting is interfering with it, so I would like to disable this feature.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the edit, I couldn't add the picture since I am a new user.

Comment: What color scheme are you using - Monokai?

Comment: Yes, I am using the default color scheme in addition with the plugin "Colorcoder"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem you're experience actually isn't the fault of Color Highlighter, it's an issue with the CSS language definition. It's easy to fix, but requires a bit of setup first.

In ST3, packages are stored in zipped `.sublime-package` files, so to edit the language definition we'll need to extract the CSS package. This is easily accomplished using the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. Install it through Package Control, then open the Command Palette and type ***`prv`*** to get the `Package Resource Viewer:` options. Select **`Package Resource Viewer: Open Resource`**, navigate down the list to `CSS`, then open the `CSS.tmLanguage` file. You should now be able to edit this file and save it, which will create a new file `Packages/CSS/CSS.tmLanguage` (where `Packages` is the folder opened by the **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** menu item) that you can open directly via the file menu if you need to alter it again. If you want to extract an entire package, just choose the **`Package Resource Viewer: Extract Package`** option.

Now that you've opened `CSS.tmLanguage` (set the syntax to XML if it isn't already), scroll down to line 291, which should read

```xml
<string>invalid.deprecated.color.w3c-non-standard-color-name.css</string>
```

Change it to

```xml
<string>support.constant.color.color-name.css</string>
```

then save the file, and you should be all set. If the changes don't show up right away, try restarting Sublime - you may also need to close and reopen your file.

If everything worked (and it should), your CSS file should now look something like this (with the cursor in `darkred`:

[image: underlined_solid]

If you would like all colors to be filled instead of underlined, open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Color Highlighter -> Settings-User`** and, if it is empty, add the following:

```js
{
    "ha_style": "filled"
}
```

If the file already has some contents, just add `"ha_style": "filled"` as the last line (make sure you put a comma `,` after the previous line). Save the file, switch back to your CSS file, and it should look like this now:

[image: filled]

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoroughly described procedure, I'll try it tomorrow and I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: So in fact it was not so long since you described so well the procedure and I could do it all. Unfortunately it only worked partially for me. The purple color is gone and instead I just have the  Monokaî background. The color is showing fully only when I put my cursor in it. Here is another screenshot of the result [link](http://hpics.li/551bd0d).

Comment: (sorry, couldn't edit quick enough my comment that I accidentally posted)

I restarted SublimeText, closed and reopened my css file and even restarted my computer but it doesn't change. I wonder if I might have some problems because I am using Linux ? Or another plugin might mess with my setup ?

Comment: @nadidja you are correct. I took the screenshot on ST2, where the settings were different. Please see my edit above for instructions on how to highlight all the colors at once.

Comment: Thank you for taking again the time to look for it ! You solved my problem in such a clear way ! It works perfectly !

Comment: is there a way to create more contrasted text respect to the background, regardless of the colour?